# Vuex router push with parameters not working

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

The data.product.slug is fine when tested on console log

```
this.router.push({ name: 'preview', params: { slug: data.product.slug } })
```

This does not work in vuex?

Comment: use `this.$router.push()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I accidentally omitted the $router but it still didn't work, ended using this code

```
const product = data.product.slug
this.$router.push({ path: `/preview/${product}` })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling it from a component you should a the  `$` because you are calling a [prototype](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Base-Example) and the convention is to have a dollar sign before, and of course Router follows it.

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'preview', params: { slug: data.product.slug } })
```